# Why am I getting an error?(multidimensional arrays in C)

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a C tutorial and currently I'm learning something about multidimensional arrays.
The code looks like this:

```
int main() {

    const int columns = 3;
    const int rows = 2;

    int grades[rows][columns] = {
        {12,23,67},
        {64,78,89}
    };

    for(int i = 0; i< rows; i++){
        for(int j= 0; j< columns; j++){

            printf("%d ", grades[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is `multarray.c:9:5: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized`.

And another warning that I'm getting is `warning: excess elements in array initializer`

Can maybe someone explain what I have to change and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Because `grades` is a  [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is created at run-time. it can't be initialized by the compiler. Either you need to make the dimensions compile-time constants (e.g. macros) or you need to figure out some other way to initialize the array.

Comment: If you already know the elements' data to hard code, then you can also hard code the array dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I replaced rows and columns with the values and it works now but is there some other way to initialize the array so that I can keep the rows and columns as they are? I'll look into it

Comment: Since `enum`s are real constants, you can use `enum {rows = 2, columns = 3};`